# Get Object Reference Error when trying to use Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, nullreferenceexception

I have a page.aspx that reads the query string, and if the QueryString is something like page.aspx?id=1, it runs some code.

However, I want it to simply ignore that code if no QueryString is specified. If I simply go to page.aspx. Right now, the only code I have on page load is

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"].Equals("1"))
  {
     //Do something
  }
```

That works if I go to page.aspx?id=1. However, simply going to page.aspx gives me this error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

How can I load the page with no query string?

Comment: Your problem is that you are not also checking for nulls: 
`Request.QueryString["id"] != "" && Request.QueryString["id"] != null)`

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check for nulls

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null && Request.QueryString["id"].Equals("1"))
{
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
if(Request.QueryString.Length != 0)
{
   ...
}
```

If you try to access elements which are not present, you'll receive an exception. So, since `QueryString` has a property of `Length`, checking it against 0 means there is no query string at all.

Else if you want to know that only if `id` key isn't present, you can do this:

```
if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("id"))
{

}
```

Comment: IMO it would be better to check if the `QueryString` key is `id` or not also. +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

This will cover any null reference issues or when there simply is an empty query string

```
if (Request.QueryString != null && Request.QueryString["id"] != null && Request.QueryString["id"] == "1")
{
//do work
}
```

Comment: that will not compile

Comment: @Selman22 you are right, don't know what I was thinking there, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null && Request.QueryString["id"].Equals("1"))
{
 //Do something
}
```

Another way :

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"] ?? "";
if(id == "1")
{
     //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see this error :

```
     object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Know that you are checking for something that is null or simply doesn't exist

so try this :

```
    if(Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
     {
        if (Request.QueryString["id"].Equals("1"))
        {
               //Do something
        }
     }
```

Comment: `Request.QueryString.Length` will never be `null`, I guess.

Comment: And what if there is a `QueryString` value exists and its not `id`?

Comment: if the ID is always an int so you can use int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["whatever"]) then if it returns true , then it's an id which you can use

Comment: `Request.QueryString.Length` will return `int`, so the default value will always be 0 (if no query string exists). And if there is a query string, there is no guaranty that it should be `"id"`.

Comment: Edited : Ops sorry for that , i added the length property by mistake, sorry

Comment: But still it can't be predicted that the `QueryString` will be for `"id"`. You need to check for `null` value for `Request.QueryString["id"]` also

Comment: flu makes more than that :D you're totally true , sorry for that